# Batteries in which wristwatches last longer: digital or mechanical display

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

I was wondering how digital watches (ex: Casio G-Shock, not smartwatches which have rechargeable batteries) compare with their (battery-operated but with mechanical display) counterparts (those with dials and hands) when it comes to draining batteries? Assuming I rarely switch on the backlight on digital watch or use extra features like alarm.

Comment: Isn't that simply something that you can read from the prospects or ask the people who make the watches?

Comment: ??? quartz watches ARE digital. Only the output mechanism is different.

Comment: What kind of car gets better fuel economy, a sedan or a red one?

Comment: Seems that folks don't get your point. Perhaps edit your question to ask "how does a mechanical solenoid escapement mechanism compare with Liquid-crystal display regarding current consumption in quartz driven timepieces"?

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes no sense since both types of watches you mention use a quartz crystal as the timing element.  Put another way, any normal "digital watch" is also a "quartz watch".

Furthermore, just about any watch today is a "quartz watch".  *Think* about it.  Quartz as apposed to what?  Old tick-tock mechanical movements are much more costly to manufacture, take more space, and are not as accurate as quartz crystals.  About the only advantage to a watch with mechanical timing is that it doesn't use batteries.  These generally get the energy to operate from you winding up a spring.

The broader issue is that marketing terms that take on a life of their own are not useful in engineering, and this is a engineering site.  If you don't really understand what terms mean, like "quartz watch" and "digital watch", then you shouldn't use them as if you do.  It would be acceptable to ask here about such terms, then use them in a question once you understand what they really mean.